# Append POST data javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using either Javascript and/or Jquery how can I append POST data to a form to submit.  I have in my server side code that will check to see if the post data dictionary contains a certain key.

I already have a form in the code.  So I would just like to use javascript to add a new key to the POST data.

Comment: Both the answers from Jarry and Fabrizio will get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quick example

you can add hidden inputs, for example:

```
var yourValue = 123;
$('form').append('<input type="hidden" id="yourData" name="yourData" value="'+ yourValue +'"/>');
```

so you get:

```
<input type="hidden" id="yourData" name="yourData" value="123"/>
```

and when you do the submit you are sending "yourData"

Comment: this was simple and easy... that's all I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

with jQuery:

```
var $input = $('<input>').attr(
{
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'input_id',
    name: 'input_name',
    value: 'input_value'
}).appendTo('#form_name');

$('#form_name').submit();
```

is this what you were trying to do?

Comment: This needs to be wrapped into an event, such as the actual submit. `$('#form_name').submit(function (){ //your code here/ return false; });`

Comment: i usually use a button input, with a click event to do this. but wrapping it into submit may work, IDK

Answer (score 1):

try to intercept the submit event and:

- serialize the form, add what you need to add and use the `$.post(url, data, function(){});` function.
- inject the form with extra hidden input fields and then submit it via jquery